# Why mapcentercoord not display value?

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet

I use the plugin L. Control. Mapcentercoord in the leaflet map but when I use

```
L.control.mapCenterCoord({
      latLngFormatter: function (lat, lng) {
        //calculate the geo hash (to show combining lat and long); display it as a link (to show how to customise the display)
        var geohash = encodeGeoHash(lat, lng);
        return '<a href="https://www.flickr.com/nearby/' + lat + ',' + lng + '?taken=alltime">' + geohash + '</a>'
      },
      onMove: true
    }).addTo(map);
```

value in return is not recorded in the folder. I should be able to click on lat,lng. All browsers are already tried but still the same problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: Full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please. I suspect you might be using an outdated copy of `L.Control.MapCenterCoord.min.js`.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin through this url https://github.com/xguaita/Leaflet.MapCenterCoord . And this is an example of what I've done. https://selakarweb.ml/btproject

Comment: Yup, outdated. Compare https://selakarweb.ml/btproject/src/L.Control.MapCenterCoord.js vs https://github.com/xguaita/Leaflet.MapCenterCoord/blob/master/src/L.Control.MapCenterCoord.js , and the READMEs at https://github.com/xguaita/Leaflet.MapCenterCoord/blob/master/README.md vs the readme inside the 0.7 release at https://github.com/xguaita/Leaflet.MapCenterCoord/releases/tag/v0.7